# ODBC query - refresh data pushing the last row of data down

Tags: excel, odbc

I have a simple ODBC connection to a SQL database in Excel. 
Usually I would just refresh all, and the new data will appear at the bottom row. There are 2 columns which are manual inputs (Sold and Settled).
The query will pick up CustName and Amount.

```
CustName Amount Sold Settled
Cust1     100      1 10.5.2020
Last1      50      1 10.5.2020
```

Now when I refresh the data.
It used to just leave all the manual inputs alone.
Now it shifted the last row of manual inputs.
New 2 should have Sold and Settled blank... but I'm finding that it took the values from Last1, and Last1 is now blank when it should have kept the record.

```
CustName Amount Sold Settled
Cust1     100      1 10.5.2020
Last1      50      
New1       20     
New2       10      1 10.5.2020
```

Any ideas?

It should look like this after a refresh.

```
CustName Amount Sold Settled
Cust1     100      1 10.5.2020
Last1      50      1 10.5.2020     
New1       20     
New2       10
```

Excel version is 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this question. I've excluded the manual input columns from the table range. This no longer moves with the ODBC query results.